# Why isn't my or statement working, C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a function that will replace 0's, 1's, or 2's with spaces in a string. I'm going about it by iterating through the string and comparing each individual character.

My function will work if I compare **str_in[i] == '0'**, but if I add the or statement it returns nothing.

Snippet:

```
string omit_num( string ) {
    int i ;

    str_len = str_in.length();
    str_out = "" ; 

    for( i = 0 ; i < str_len ; i ++ ){
         cout << str_in[i] << endl; 
         if ( str_in[i] == '0' || '1' || '2') 
            app = " " ;
         else
             app = str_in[i];
         str_out.append(app) ; 
    }
    return str_out; 

}
```

Comment: wow, nine answers... and they all say the same thing.

Comment: And your compiler should warn you about expressions that will always evaluate to true/false.

Comment: (Apart from the error all the posts have told about) this snippet is obviously not the code you used, and will not compile on its own.

Comment: where is app declared?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need

```
if ( str_in[i] == '0' ||  str_in[i] =='1' ||  str_in[i] =='2')
```

Answer (score 6):

You will have to repeat the test each time, '1', '2' on their own are basically small ints and evaluate to true.  It should look like the following:

```
if (str_in[i] == '0' || str_in[i] == '1' || str_in[i] == '2')
```

Answer (score 4):

The expression `str_in[i] == '0' || '1' || '2'` contains three separate expressions:

```
str_in[i] == '0'
'1'
'2'
```

According to any ASCII chart, '0' has a value of 48, '1' is 49, '2' is 50. So the last two expressions are always non-zero (and therefore always true).

You probably wanted `str_in[i] == '0' || str_in[i] == '1' || str_in[i] == '2'`

Answer (score 4):

```
if (str_in[i] == '0' || str_in[i] == '1' || str_in[i] == '2')
```

or alternatively

```
switch (str_in[i]) {
  case '0':
  case '1':
  case '2': app = " " ;
            break;
  default:  app = str_in[i];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

'1' is '1' therefore '1' evaluates to true. You must make new, complete, statements with every operator.

try this:

`if ( str_in[i] == '0' || str_in[i] == '1' || str_in[i] == '2' )`

Comment: `'1'` is a char, and *evaluates* to `true`. However, `'1' == true` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: You are correct my choice of wording was incorrect. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

Your if statement reads as follows: If the character at `i` is equal to `'0'`,  or `'1'` is true, or `'2'` is true. As `'1'` and `'2'` both evaluate to a non zero integer, it will always be true.

What you want is: `str_in[i] == '0' || str_in[i] == '1' || str_in[i] == '2'`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the logic overall, but the logic here specifically is wrong.  Replace

```
if ( str_in[i] == '0' || '1' || '2')
```

with

```
if ( str_in[i] == '0' || str_in[i] == '1' || str_in[i] == '2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your if statement to:

```
if ( str_in[i] == '0' || str_in[i] == '1' || str_in[i] == '2') {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string omit_num( string ) { 
int i ; 

str_len = str_in.length(); 
str_out = "" ;  

for( i = 0 ; i < str_len ; i ++ ){ 
     cout << str_in[i] << endl;  
     if ( str_in[i] == '0' || '1' || '2')  
        app = " " ; 
     else 
         app = str_in[i]; 
     str_out.append(app) ;  
} 
return str_out;
```

}

this would work as the following:

```
string omit_num( string ) { 
int i ; 

str_len = str_in.length(); 
str_out = "" ;  

for( i = 0 ; i < str_len ; i ++ ){ 
     cout << str_in[i] << endl;  
     if ( (str_in[i] == '0') || (str_in[i] == '1') || (str_in[i] == '2'))  
        app = " " ; 
     else 
         app = str_in[i]; 
     str_out.append(app) ;  
} 
return str_out;
```

}

Comment: I love it when programmers use parenthesis! Seriously. Why trust/look up precedence when you can make it clearly explicit?

Comment: This is the only way I like to do things and wished more programmers would... Obviously know its not necessary but still like to keep it understood... makes harder sequences much easier to debug later...

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the equality operator in each || expression:

```
if (str_in[i] == '0' || str_in[i] == '1' || str_in[i] == '2')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using c++, use the standard library already:

```
std::replace_if( s.begin(), s.end(), [](char a){return a=='0'||a=='1'||a=='2';}, ' ');
```